# 1997 Geo Metro Stalled when I hit a hole in road and will not restart

Tags: starting

Hit a hole in the road the car stopped & now acts like it is out of gas.  Is there a reset somewhere for the gas, in case it was shut off some how as an emergency thing when I hit the hole. I looked in the trunk, not one there, looked in the book couldn't find it there.

Answer (score 1):

Look in your owners manual - it will be referred to as something equivalent to a fuel pump inertia switch.  I don't have a manual handy but the best candidate location that I've been able to find is on top of the fuel tank.

Answer (score 1):

There is no reset switch for the fuel pump on GM cars. That's more of a Ford thing, they have them on almost if not all of their cars. There may be other manufacturers that do the same thing but GM is not one of them.

I always thought the reason Ford did it was because of the [Pinto fiasco in 1977](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ford_Pinto#Fuel_tank_controversy), but I couldn't find any supporting documentation.

The main relay and the fuel pump relay would be an easy check as the possible problems. The next step is to confirm that you are not getting any fuel. Spray carburetor cleaner or starting fluid into the intake while attempting to start the vehicle. If the engine runs while you are spraying it in and stops when you do then it's definitely a fuel problem and more testing of the fuel system and components is needed.

Comment: Are you sure?  This looks like the correct part: http://www.theautopartsshop.com/auto+car-usa+parts+year/geo+metro+electric-fuel-pump-inertia-switch+1997.html

Comment: @BobCross I could be wrong, but I have never seen one on the car. I worked for a GM dealer as a tech when the metro was on the road. It looks like the part is a universal fit and not a direct replacement.

Comment: Look at the following cars that have the same part number for the switch [1997 Buick Lesabre Electric Fuel Pump Inertia Switch](http://www.theautopartsshop.com/search/default.aspx?make=buick&model=lesabre&year=1997&submodel=all&engine=all&parts=Electric%20Fuel%20Pump%20Inertia%20Switch) and [2000 Toyota Echo Electric Fuel Pump Inertia Switch](http://www.theautopartsshop.com/search/default.aspx?make=toyota&model=echo&year=2000&submodel=all&engine=all&parts=Electric%20Fuel%20Pump%20Inertia%20Switch)

Comment: @BobCross Also a look at the wiring diagram and could not find an inertia switch in the fuel pump circuit.

Comment: Fair enough - that said, we're not actually helping to answer the question.  On a 97, is it possible / likely that someone retrofit the part inline with the fuel pump?

Comment: @BobCross I edited my answer to get back to the point, fixing the car :)